# Halide cross-compilation for GPU

Tags: halide

I want to run a Halide code on a GPU. There is a tutorial example on how to run on GPU and how to do cross-compilation. But, there is no tutorial combining cross-compilation with running on GPU.

I have tried to do the same way as the method in the cross-compilation tutorial. But I am not sure the configuration of the target.

```
target.os = Target::Windows; 
target.arch = Target::X86; 
target.bits = 64;
...

target.os = Target::Windows; // ???
target.arch = ??? ;
target.bits = 64;
std::vector<Target::Feature> gpu_features;
gpu_features.push_back(Target::OpenCL);
brighter.compile_to_file(...);
```

I develop the code in Ubuntu running on a virtual machine while the host machine OS is Windows. That's why I need to do the cross-compilation in order to run on a GPU.

Is it supported or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand a bit, Halide can generate code for multiple GPU/accelerator/offload architectures in a single filter. The `Target` specifies the architecture/OS/address-width for the CPU the host code will run on, plus the set of external execution APIs that are allowed. `Funcs` can be scheduled out to any of those APIs, e.g. OpenCL, OpenGL, Cuda, etc. In fact, in order to get anything to run on a GPU, appropriate scheduling must be provided.

The code that will run on the accelerator or GPU is embedded inside a function that runs on the CPU architecture specified by the top-level `Target`.

One can write Halide code that interoperates fairly seamlessly between OpenCL and OpenGL for example.

Ultimately we plan to support running GPU(etc) code from source code languages we support (currently C++, JavaScript is in a branch).

It is not possible to generate standalone code for a GPU. E.g. one cannot get OpenCL without the CPU code wrapper that invokes the code.

Comment: Just want to clarify, I create an example adapted from "using_the_gpu" tutorial. I changed `curved.compile_jit()` with `curved.compile_to_file(...)`. So, it generated the kernel openCL code. So, in this case, is the CPU code (including copy_to_device() and copy_from_device() API) needed to call the GPU kernel code, generated automatically by Halide? In my windows project, I just need to specify the input and call the function from the generated H file, is it correct?

Comment: Yes, Halide generates CPU code to invoke the kernels on the GPU and puts them in a single C/C++ callable function with appropriate inputs and outputs. The OpenCL code is an internal detail of the generated function from the callers point of view. You will need to make the copy_from_device calls to ensure the data is valid on host before accessing it on the CPU outside of Halide. (Accesses inside of Halide should be handled automatically.) This is done so multiple GPU filters can be run back-to-back without unnecessary host/device copies.

Answer (score 1):

There is still CPU code to call the GPU code. So you should generate your H and OBJ or LIB file on Ubuntu and use them on Windows from your Windows project.

Comment: ... and target.arch is the architecture for the CPU code, so use x86.